# Check if user credentials are correct in Login page without reloading the page? [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

So I noticed this neat thing on Zapier's [login page](https://zapier.com/app/login). When you enter wrong credentials and click on 'Login', it gives you the 'Incorrect email or password' error without even reloading the page. How is this being done? And how can I replicate it in my Rails app with Devise?

Comment: You will have to use some sort of JavaScript in order to create an asynchronous request which will basically send the filled information (username//password) to your controller. The controller in return will evaluate the information and return some kind of value (basically up to you). Depending on the answer, you will either show an error (wrong username//password) or log the user in and redirect further. Your question is too broad to basically provide _the_ answer.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner That's actually _the_ answer :) I was just looking for a brief overview of how it worked; I can figure the rest out myself. Post this as an answer if you don't mind so I can mark it as solved!

Comment: Alright, gonna do that :) Glad I could help nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without providing code, but rather a general answer, here you go:

In order to create an asynchronous request, you basically want to hook up with some sort of JavaScript (jQuery, AngularJs, ...) which issues an asynchronous request (keyword: AJAX) to your Ruby on Rails Controller. Make sure to include the username/password as params for the controller to evaluate it ;)

Depending on the entered information and your desired behavior, your controller with respond with json (Something as simple as `render json: true, status: 200` should already do the job.) which then, evaluated on the clientside again, will either show an error or redirect the user further.

This tutorial may help you on the way:
https://hackhands.com/sign-users-ajax-using-devise-rails/

Good luck!